# How would you replace a devise form with a code snippet?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this signup page snippet that I want to use. My issue is I am using devise with my rails app so I'm not sure how to replace the fields in the snippet with the ruby code while retaining styles.

This is the code from devise in my view

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :email, :class=>'formlabel' %><br />
          <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :password, :class=>'formlabel' %>
          <% if @minimum_password_length %>
          <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
          <% end %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, :class=>'formlabel' %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= render "teachers/shared/links" %>
```

and this is the snippet

```
<div class="container-fluid stylish-form">
  <h2 class="text-center">Stylish Signup Page Using Bootstrap</h2>
  <div class="row mar20">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="inner-section">
        <form method="POST" action="https://google.co.in">
          <div class="mar20 inside-form">
            <h2 class="font_white text-center">SIGN UP</h2>
            <ul>
              <li class="icon-holder dsp-flex">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook "></i>
              </li>
              <li class="icon-holder dsp-flex">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter "></i>
              </li>
              <li class="icon-holder dsp-flex">
                <i class="fa fa-instagram "></i>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil "></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="First Name...">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope "></i></span>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="Email...">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock "></i></span>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="Password...">
            </div>
            <div class="footer text-center">
              <a href="http://vijender.in/" class="btn btn-neutral btn-round btn-lg">Get Started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="text-center font_white">Thank You For Visiting This Snippet</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your the `<input>` tags in your snippet. with the `<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>` on the original forms. Add any other missing options like placeholders and such.

Compare the resulting HTML, ultimately it will be the same.